# Bloomberg API in Python: How to Get Historical Reference Data

Tags: python, python-2.7, bloomberg

I'm trying to figure out how to get historical reference data through bloomberg api in python. Essentially, I am attempting to reproduce the following excel BDH in python:

```
=BDH("IBM US EQUITY","3MTH_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF","2015-01-01","2016-01-01")
```

None of the python packages I've found seem to offer this functionality. For instance, while I can get reference data through tia:

```
from tia.bbg import LocalTerminal
resp = LocalTerminal.get_reference_data('SPX Index','3MTH_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF')
```

I can't figure out how to pull the historical time series of implied vol as opposed to the single datapoint.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you haven't found it but it is in tia.
`get_historical` is the function name.
The function to use is:
`resp = LocalTerminal.get_historical('SPX Index','3MTH_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF', start="2015-01-01",end="2016-01-01")`

You might have to do something like `resp.as_frame()` to get the dataframe of data.

I encourage you to go through the tia github to examine the code to understand how to get historical data for your other needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the [pdblp](https://github.com/matthewgilbert/pdblp/) package and `ref_hist()` function in particular. (Disclaimer: I am the author). This function acts as a simple wrapper to provide iterative calls to the `ReferenceDataRequest` Bloomberg Open API service, overriding the associated date field for the particular ticker, e.g. `REFERENCE_DATE`, `CURVE_DATE`, etc.

I don't currently have access to a Bloomberg terminal so cannot tell you what the date field for `3MTH_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF` is, but a simple example you should be able to adapt for your purposes is:

```
import pdblp
con = pdblp.BCon()
con.start()
con.ref_hist('AUD1M Curncy', 'DAYS_TO_MTY', dates=['20150625', '20150626'],
             date_field="REFERENCE_DATE")
```

Comment: related question, will this work with bulkref_hist? like i'm trying to query historical index members with pdblp and it won't override the date parameter